# How do I render a Cairo drawing to a printer in Haskell gtk2hs

Tags: haskell, printing, gtk2hs

I'm using the [GTK3 build of gtk2hs](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gtk-0.14.7). I have a Cairo drawing in the [`Render` monad](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/cairo-0.13.4.1/docs/Graphics-Rendering-Cairo.html#t:Render) and I want to send it to a printer.

I see that there is a `Surface` type which encapsulates the Cairo back end. For example it is possible to create an SVG surface using [`withSVGSurface`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/cairo-0.13.4.1/docs/Graphics-Rendering-Cairo.html#g:13), and there are similar functions for PDF, Postscript and PNG. Once you have a `Surface` you can apply a `Render` action (i.e. actually draw on it) using [`renderWith`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/cairo-0.13.4.1/docs/Graphics-Rendering-Cairo.html#v:renderWith). This is perfectly straightforward, and I can see how to use these functions to export drawings as files.

However printing does not seem to work this way. The [`printOptDrawPage`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gtk-0.14.7/docs/Graphics-UI-Gtk-Printing-PrintOperation.html#v:printOptDrawPage) signal provides its callback with a [`printContext`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gtk-0.14.7/docs/Graphics-UI-Gtk-Printing-PrintContext.html) value. This has a function `printContextGetCairoContext` which returns a Cairo `Context`. However the library documentation doesn't have an entry for this `Context` type, and I can't find any functions that use it.

It looks like there ought to be `printContextGetSurface` function, or else a way to convert a `Context` into a `Surface`. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hah, whoops, that's embarrassing! It seems the bindings are just a little incomplete in this department.

Luckily it should be pretty easy to update them. Taking a look at the definition of the `Render` monad:

```
newtype Render m = Render { runRender :: ReaderT Cairo IO m }
```

We can see that the `Cairo` object you get from `printContextGetCairoContext` is just what you need to do something useful with a `Render` action. The implementation of the `renderWith` function gives you a clue about what cleanup actions you should take:

```
renderWith surface (Render m) = liftIO $
  bracket (Internal.create surface)
          (\context -> do status <- Internal.status context
                          Internal.destroy context
                          unless (status == StatusSuccess) $
                            fail =<< Internal.statusToString status)
          (\context -> runReaderT m context)
```

I think one of two patches would be sensible here:

1. Expose a `renderWith`-alike that consumes a `Cairo`. Let the user connect up `printContextGetCairoContext` with the new `renderWith`-alike.
2. Don't expose `printContextGetCairoContext` at all; replace it with

   ```
   printContextRender :: PrintContextClass self => self -> Render a -> IO a
   ```

   and have `printContextRender` merge the call to `printContextGetCairoContext` with the `renderWith`-style cleanup.

I like option (1) for its clean backwards-compatibility story; but I like (2) a lot better from the API-design side of things. Since this module probably hasn't seen much use for the reasons you're describing, I'd lean towards patch (2).

I'd also note that you may want to look into the gtk documentation a bit to check whether the Cairo context cleanup is somebody else's responsibility (the PrintOperation's, for example).

Happy hacking!

Comment: @PaulJohnson That's great, and I applaud that action. But in the interest of transparency: I expect if this is a feature you need, it's going to be up to you to make it happen.